# Thmbnail Cycle using django template language

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to cycle through my images to present in one col but seems I can't make it work. Tried different ways but couldn't get help form official docs either.
Would be glad to get solutions from anyone. Following is the code:

```
<section class="banner-home-bottom container">

  <div class="widget-title wow fadeIn">

    <fieldset class="box-title lang1">
      <legend align="center">#Featured On Ella </legend>
    </fieldset>


  </div>
{% for object in object_list %}
    <div class="row">
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
      <a href="#"><img src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="" /></a>
      <div class="des">

        <h4 style="color: #000000;font-size: 20px;">
          <span class="lang1">{{ object.title }}</span>


        </h4>
        <p style="color: #2d2d2d;font-size: 12px;">
          <span class="lang1">{{ object.description }}.</span>


        </p>
          <a href="#" title="Shop Now " class="btn lang1">
            Shop Now
            <span class="arrow">arrow</span>
          </a>

      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
        {% cycle "" "" "" "</div><br/><hr/><div class='row'>" %}
        </div>
</section>


{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is it M2M field? Did you try `{% for image in object_list.images.all %}{{ image.filename }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: No its not many to many field for images. So far I assigned images to all items in development mode so no reason for this I guess.

Comment: So where do you store the images? You can run another query just for your images.